# Apache httpPost change https to http in url

Tags: java

i want to call https post method with apache httpclient.
i dont find solution in internet.
the problem is when i call method https change to http and i dont know why?!

i tried many ways.but all of them change https to http in url.

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(20000)
        .setSocketTimeout(20000)
        .build();

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
    "  <soap:Body>\n" +
    "    <GetComplaintData xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n" +
    "      <UserName></UserName>\n" +
    "      <Password></Password>\n" +
    "      <TrackingCode>"+complaintCode+"</TrackingCode>\n" +
    "    </GetComplaintData>\n" +
    "  </soap:Body>\n" +
    "</soap:Envelope>", "UTF-8");


HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.create('POST')
        .setConfig(requestConfig)
        .setUri("https://195.cra.ir:8085/Complaint.asmx?op=GetComplaintData")
        .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml;charset=UTF-8")
        .setEntity(entity)
        .build();

HttpClientBuilder.create().build().withCloseable {httpClient ->

    httpClient.execute(request).withCloseable {response ->

        String res = "RESPONSE:" + "\n" + response.getStatusLine() + "\n" + "Headers: " +
                response.getAllHeaders() + "\n" +
                (response.getEntity() != null ? EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()) : "") + "\n";

         println(res.toString()+"_________________________-")
    }
}
```

i expect url dont change https to http.
sorry if i explain it bad.thanks

Comment: Why do you think it's being changed? Internally it uses the `java.net.URI`, so if it can be parsed, it must stay as it is. What's the `uri` value when you inspect `request`?

Comment: hi.you are right uri dont change .can you add example of httpPost for https??
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find plenty of examples on the Web just by searching for: `apache http client post`. In any case, this should work for you, depending on the version you are using:

```
final String envelope = "<soap:Envelope ... </soap:Envelope>";
final StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(envelope, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
entity.setChunked(true);
final HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://your.url?soap=Operation");
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.addHeader("SOAPAction", "YourSOAPActionHere");
final CloseableHttpResponse response = HttpClients.createDefault().execute(httpPost);
response.getStatusLine();
EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: i use the code but error still exist.

{
  "errorCode": 400,
  "errors": "Connect to 195.cra.ir:8085 [195.cra.ir/185.155.236.64] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)\nConnection timed out (Connection timed out)\n"
}